# copy file owned by another user to my account

Tags: linux, permissions, file-copy

I have two accounts, dnc1 and dnc2, both are not root accounts.

I want to login dnc1 account and copy a file owned dnc2 to dnc1 directory. The file mode is 644 and the folder containing it is 755. So the public is able to read both the file and the folder.

In the past, I can copy the file without problem.

However, today I get the following error:

```
cannot access xxx: Permission denied
```

Why?

**Update**

I figure out the issue. After tracing back to the parent dir, and then parent dir, all these dirs are 755, until I find one public_html that is 750. After setting it to 755, then it is OK again.

The problem is that I have already set it to 755 in the past. Will Apache auto-change it to 750 from time to time?

Comment: What about the perms of the directory (tree) containing the directory in question?

Comment: can you give us the output of `ls -lZ /path/to/file/xxx` and `getfacl /path/to/file/xxx`?

Comment: @tink, I figure out the reason. But it seems system or Apache will auto-change public_html from 755 to 750

Comment: @alancc apache itself definitely doesn't do that, and it's not generally a feature of any distro I'm aware of. But it's a good idea to *not* make directories in public_html executable to anyone; that stop path traversals by unprivileged processes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Thank you very much. I set the folder back to 750 and add dnc1 to the group of dnc2, which also solved the issue.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, After setting to 750, all the pages under public_html will shows 403 forbidden error. So I have to set it to 755 again(I tried 754 also not working)

Comment: @alancc that sounds like the apache server runs as a different user or group than you marked the files

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I use ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)' and find there are several httpd, one is running via root, the others are running with nobody. None of them is dnc2.